# Easing and timer event AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My meter looks great and the needle rotates in a loop. How do I add easing to it?

The meter is built from a timer event.  I want the needle to bounce at the end. Rather than just adding a variable, I need some control of when it happens so I can adjust it with the animation.

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon8.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/icon8.jpg)

## WORKING CODE "Thxs to member"

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(20, 30);//tick 200, 36<br>

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startAgain); 

timer.start(); 

function startAgain($evt:TimerEvent):void { 
    timer.reset(); 
    timer.start(); 
} 

function onTimer($evt:TimerEvent):void { 
    watch.hand.rotation = 30 + timer.currentCount;//tick 5 
}
```

## FAILED ATTEMPT "needle's crazy, it's just suppose to bounce"

```
//the "tick" may mess up the effect

import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(20, 30);//tick 200, 36
  var startValue:Number = watch.hand.rotation;
  var finishValue:Number = 33;//400
  var duration:Number = 222;//3
  var myTween:Tween = new Tween(watch.hand, "rotation", Elastic.easeOut, startValue, finishValue, duration, false);//true
  myTween.looping = true;
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer); 
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, startAgain); 

timer.start(); 

function startAgain($evt:TimerEvent):void { 
    timer.reset(); 
    timer.start(); 
} 
function onTimer($evt:TimerEvent):void { 
    watch.hand.rotation = 30 + timer.currentCount;//tick 5
 //watch.x =+ 66;

}
```

EXPERIMENT
My project will requires a higher understanding of timer events and tweening. If I can get this animation to do stuff, I think I can better understand how to pass function calls and set up events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pfunc mentioned, this is going to be far easier to accomplish with a third party tweening library.  It can be done with fl.transitions.Tween, but the chaining of tweens and onComplete handling is less than desirable.

As mentioned, check out one of these:

[GTween](http://gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/)

[TweenLite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/)

[Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/)

All of these 3 have a very similar API (which is far better than Flash's built-in Tween - IMHO)

When I helped out with your original question about the Timer class, I did not realize that this is what you wanted to do.  The Timer class is not a suitable choice for this problem as it is intended for events to be handled on consistent basis.

Comment: Ya, I can't recommend enough that people don't use the fl.transitions packages. We don't even allow it in our projects.

Comment: @VideoDnd, I would actually give the check mark to @pfunc.  After all, he had the same answer as me some 12 minutes before.

Comment: I'll go back to tweenlite maybe. My projects all involve loops, tweens, repetative motion that frame animation can't handle. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use another tweening engine for this. Check out tweener or gtween. Makes things easier for animating and you can call functions when a tween has finished animating. You can create custom tweens and adjust how much bounce you want. There might be a way to do this with flash's built in tweening engine, but not sure how.